# iCalendar events imported in Google Calendar are empty

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

When importing a ics file ("iCalendar") into Google Calendar, the import proceed successfully and all event appear in the calendar, but all fields of the events are empty.

The only information displayed is "busy" ("occupé(e)" on the screenshot).

- No error message is displayed during the import.
- The ics file is validated fine by multiple validation libraries and online tools.

[image: screenshot of Google Calendar after import]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused in my case by the `CLASS` property of my events being `PRIVATE` or `CONFIDENTIAL`.

See [RFC 2245](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt), section 4.8.1.3 "Classification".

Since the ics is added to Google Calendar *via* a public link, Google considers that it should not read and/or display the content of events not marked as `PUBLIC`.

So the solution was to change the class of my events to

```
CLASS:PUBLIC
```

---

Note that this is probably a misinterpretation of the spec, as it is clearly stated that:

> [...] due to the "blind" nature of most exchange
>      processes using this memo, **these access classifications cannot serve
>      as an enforcement statement for a system receiving an iCalendar
>      object**. Rather, they provide a method for capturing the intention of
>      the calendar owner for the access to the calendar component.

Emphasis mine.